# Warn about not initialized variables

Tags: java, eclipse

Can I make Eclipse display me ALL uninitialized Variables? Also primitives? This bothered me for a long time, sometiems I forgot about initializing a boolean which then was a Boolean, so it was null...
Apart from that, is there a plugin dedicated to generally wipe out code smell?

Comment: java, sry forgot that eclipse supports multiple lngs XD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [PMD](http://pmd.sourceforge.net/) as a plugin - it might give you too much information but you could configure it to only show the information you want